# Partitioning strategy in Parquet and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a job that reads csv files , converts it into data frames and writes in Parquet. I am using append mode while writing the data in Parquet. With this approach, in each write a separate Parquet file is getting generated. My questions are :

- 1) If every time I write the data to Parquet schema ,a new file gets
  appended , will it impact read performance (as the data is now
  distributed in varying length of partitioned Parquet files)
- 2) Is there a way to generate the Parquet partitions purely based on
  the size of the data ?
- 3) Do we need to think to a custom partitioning strategy to implement
  point 2?
  I am using Spark 2.3

Answer (score 3):

1. It will affect read performance if
   [spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema=true](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging).

   In this case, Spark needs to visit each file and grab schema from
   it.

   In other cases, I believe it does not affect read performance much.
2. There is no way generate purely on data size. You may use
   `repartition` or `coalesce`. Latter will created uneven output
   files, but much performant.

   Also, you have config `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` or  option
   `maxRecordsPerFile` to prevent big size of files, but usually it is
   not an issue.
3. Yes, I think Spark has not built in API to evenly distribute by data
   size. There are [Column
   Statistics](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-ColumnStat.html)
   and [Size
   Estimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html) may help with this.

Comment: I might have a scenario where very few records were added , in that 
    case if I use append write mode , it will create a new partition with 
    very few data . If I  use repartition or coalesce , I have to read the 
    whole Parquet data then use coalesce to merge the partition , remove 
    all the old partitions and then store this new repartitioned dataframe. Is that the right way?